# TypeScript error : TS2305: Module '"./secretManager/secret"' has no exported member

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, aws-sdk

I'm new to TypeScript. I'm getting below error but could not tried to understand its meaning:-

```
(@simpplr/integrations-fetch) $ tsc -b tsconfig.build.json src/index.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"./secretManager/secret"' has no exported member 'getWorkDayCredentials'.
error Error
error     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/vkumar/go/mywork/mydevelopment/simpplr/third-party-integrations/node_modules/bolt/dist/modern/utils/processes.js:128:16)
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

**index.ts:-**

```
import { getWorkDayCredentials } from './secretManager/secret';

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('Fetch Lambda trigger by event ', event);
    let response = null;
    try {
        //Calling Secret Manager
        let secretName = 'myworkdaysecret-dev';
        let region = 'us-east-2';
        response = await getWorkDayCredentials(region, secretName);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
    return response;
};
```

**Secret.ts:-**

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

module.exports.getWorkDayCredentials = async (region, secretName) => {
    console.log('Invoking AWS Secret Manager services');
    // Create a Secrets Manager client
    let client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
        region: region
    });
    const data = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }).promise();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
};
```

Please refer attached screenshot. While importing this getWorkDayCredentials module from secret.ts file, getting some error and also same error while building it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the standard TypeScript import & export syntax, rather than using platform-specific features like `module.exports`. In this case, you want this in `secret.ts`:

```js
export const getWorkDayCredentials = async (region, secretName) => {
    // ...
};
```

You'll also need a similar change in `index.ts`:

```js
export const lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    // ...
};
```

I'd suggest looking through the [Modules section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) of the TypeScript guidebook for more details and examples.